# Gatling, append a value to an existing list attribute in Session

Tags: list, session, attributes, append, gatling

I am Gatling and trying to append a value to an existing list attribute in Session. For example, let's suppose that the current Session has a list attribute as follow.

List(1, 2, 3)

Then, after running the code below,

```
  exec(
    http("Create_New_Lists")
    .post("/api/v1/lists/sync")
    .basicAuth("${email}", "test")
    .body(StringBody("""{ "productListDto":{"id":"0","active":"true","items":[],"name":"""" + listName + """"},"token":"" }""")).asJSON 
    .check(jsonPath("""$..id""").saveAs("value_to_be_appended"))
  )
```

I want to add "value_to_be_appended" to the list so that the list would be

List(1, 2, 3, 4) (if value_to_be_appended is 4)

How can I do this?

I would appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2):

Write a [exec block](http://gatling.io/docs/2.1.6/general/scenario.html#exec) where you [manipulate the session](http://gatling.io/docs/2.1.6/session/session_api.html), fetch the existing list and replace it:

```
.exec { session =>
   for {
     existingList <- session("existingList").validate[List[Int]]
     // the value you extracted is a String, not an Int
     value_to_be_appended <- session("value_to_be_appended").validate[String]
   } yield session.set("existingList", existingList ::: List(value_to_be_appended))
}
```